# Class 'Zend_Measure_Weight' not found - Magento

Tags: php, magento, error-handling, magento-1.9

I am getting Fatal error when I go to shipping page in `Magento (ver 1.9)`. Its saying:

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Measure_Weight' not found in
>   /home/www/mysite.com/www/newsite/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php
>   on line 439

I have this code on line 439:

```
'dimensions_variables'  => array(
                'L'         => Zend_Measure_Weight::POUND,
                'LB'        => Zend_Measure_Weight::POUND,
                'POUND'     => Zend_Measure_Weight::POUND,
                'K'         => Zend_Measure_Weight::KILOGRAM,
                'KG'        => Zend_Measure_Weight::KILOGRAM,
                'KILOGRAM'  => Zend_Measure_Weight::KILOGRAM,
                'I'         => Zend_Measure_Length::INCH,
                'IN'        => Zend_Measure_Length::INCH,
                'INCH'      => Zend_Measure_Length::INCH,
                'C'         => Zend_Measure_Length::CENTIMETER,
                'CM'        => Zend_Measure_Length::CENTIMETER,
                'CENTIMETER'=> Zend_Measure_Length::CENTIMETER,

            )
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you call it from your model, so you have to add this before your class

```
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . '/Zend/Measure/Weight.php');

class ........ extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
```

and done, you can call the `Zend_Measure_Weight` class now.